# Add to cart is not working in woocommerce 2.1.8

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woocommerce 2.1.8 . I am using the product bundle add on in woocommerce.  Add to cart is not working in case of product bundle product. It is showing empty cart and same prodcut page when I click on the add to cart button. I have set the redirect option in wocommerce settings. I have searched about the issue and delete the /woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php from the theme but issue is still there. It is working for simple product only not product bundle. Please let me know how can I fix it? I need to fix it asap.

Thanks,

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: I am using the woocommerce plugin 2.1.8 and product bundle addon

Comment: you can check the page here http://eggheadvideo.com/select-semi-custom-video/cartoon-video/